# JavaScript data access design

Tags: javascript, jquery, single-page-application

I'm writing a single page app and have made it to writing the data access layer for the client-side. My question involves the proper design of it. While I do understand JS is callback-centric, I have to wonder if there's not a better way to do data-retrieval. Here is an example of how my current data access calls are formatted with callbacks:

```
$interface.getDashboard = function (callback) {
    callback({MyApplications:[]});
};
```

Here is what I'm thinking of moving towards to eliminate the need for callbacks all over the place:

```
$interface.getApplications = function () {
    var v = amplify.store("api.applications");
    if (!v) {
        v = [];
        _get("/api/applications", null, function (results) {
            amplify.store("api.applications", results, { expires: _cacheTimeOut });
            dataRefresh();
        });
    }

    return v;
};
```

In the code above, `dataRefresh()` will tell all applicable subscribers to refresh their data. So I guess you can say it's still using callbacks but in a different manner.

**Is there a better way to do this? I've never written a strong data access layer for javascript before and would like to know if there's a pattern to follow as convention or a heuristic solution perhaps?**

Comment: There are plenty of frameworks that work with jQuery to manage your single page app design for you and allow you to avoid spaghetti code. Backbone is one

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum I've heard of backbone, but my attempt here is to understand the core of what is required, not to abstract myself and have that be just a black box.

Comment: @doogle yes, but calling `dataRefresh();` it would recall `getApplications` from all subscribers, as you stated. But I really think this is overcomplicated and callbacks or Event-driven async functions should be used

Comment: @doogle " What I implied is that you go and look at the source code :)

Comment: "I have to wonder if there's not a better way to do data-retrieval." you'll still be using callbacks somehow unless your api calls are synchronous, which defeat the purpose of using ajax. You cant escape callbacks one way or another. Callback helps separate concerns. You data access layer doesnt need to know what you do with datas , and you need to tell your business logic layer when datas are available.

Comment: @camus Yeah, I was coming to the same conclusion, but figured it couldn't hurt to ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm currently dealing with the same questions on how to design and structure the Javascript side of a new enterprise level application I'm working on.

Many of the SPA examples/templates such as HotTowel are great for showing you how to get started with SPAs, but do not give much help in terms of large scale implementation.

This [talk](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vXjVFPosQHw) by Nicholas Zakas proposes a great solution. Slides for the talk can be found [here](http://www.slideshare.net/nzakas/scalable-javascript-application-architecture).

To summarise, your client side layers should consist of:

1. A set of modules - these provide discrete units of functionality for your app. They should be completely independent of one another and only be aware of the sandbox.
2. A sandbox - this provides a consistent facade interface for the modules to work with, and acts as a controller between the modules and the application core.
3. The application core - this is the mediator responsible for module management, intercommunication, and any other core functionality required by your app (e.g. ajax requests). Only the application core should be aware of the base libraries you are using.
4. Base libraries - these provide browser normalisation and any other general purpose functionality such as DOM manipulation.

This [link](http://addyosmani.com/largescalejavascript/) expands on this design and provides some more detail.

I know this answer doesn't specifically address your data access layer, but as a more general architecture overview maybe you can apply the concepts to your particular scenario.

**Edit:**

[AuraJS](https://github.com/aurajs) is a concrete implementation of the theories outlined by Zakas, developed by Addy Osmani. It's currently in developer preview but it looks like a great starting point for ideas.

Comment: Updated answer with link to AuraJS.

Comment: I ended up implementing the mediator pattern myself without any dependencies. It was easy enough to implement and gives my application a huge amount of reuse and flexibility.